# How to fix "from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn" error with Python on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, pyserial, pexpect

I have had an old script which utilises pexpect, pyserial modules. I had this running absolutely fine before i reinstalled windows. I now cannot get it to function without displaying the following;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Guidance Automation Ltd\kingpiN Programming\KingpinProgramming.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pexpect_serial\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .serial_spawn import SerialSpawn
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pexpect_serial\serial_spawn.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pexpect import spawn
ImportError: cannot import name 'spawn' from 'pexpect' (C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\pexpect\__init__.py)
```

I have tried multiple combinations of installing the pexpect_serial, pexpect, and pyserial modules, and multiple versions of python but still no avail.
It appears to be an issue with the pexpect-serial module.

The start of the file appears as this;

```
import sys
import time
import os
import serial
import pexpect.fdpexpect
import pexpect.popen_spawn
from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn
import paramiko
from config import *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in answer to my specific question...

I did not need that module! I simply modified my code to;

```
import sys
import time
import os
import serial
import pexpect.fdpexpect
import pexpect.popen_spawn
#from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn
import paramiko
from config import *
```

Hence it ran all the way through no issues!

So in hindsight, always check modules are actually needed before frustratingly trying to force them to work.

Further to this, I believe "from pexpect_serial import SerialSpawn" would not function at all on Windows.